# C++ double field to function

Tags: c++, arrays

I have

```
void createMat(int N, double X[][N], double Y[][N]){
        for (int x = 0; x < (N / 2); x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < (N / 2); y++) {
                    X[x][y] = Y[x][y];
                }
            }
    }
```

and call it in main

```
createMat(N,A,a);
```

I do not understand, what is wrong.
I create matrix, N is number of rows and columns put by user. A is new matrix, a is the old one.

```
**main.cpp:19:35: error: use of parameter outside function body before ']' token
 void createMat(int N, double X[][N], double Y[][N]){
                                   ^
main.cpp:19:36: error: expected ')' before ',' token
 void createMat(int N, double X[][N], double Y[][N]){
                                    ^
main.cpp:19:38: error: expected unqualified-id before 'double'
 void createMat(int N, double X[][N], double Y[][N]){**
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> **main.cpp:19:35: error: use of parameter outside function body before ']' token
> void createMat(int N, double X[][N], double Y[][N]){
>                                 ^
> ```

The error message is pretty clear. You cannot use `N` at the point of parameter declarations to specify a fixed array size. The error message tells you that in general, you cannot use the parameter `N` outside of the functions body introduced with the `{}` curly braces.

**Note:**
C++ doesn't support *variable length arrays*.

Use a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` as parameter type instead, or a `std::array<std::array<double, N>, M>` where `N` and `M` are known values at compile time.

Comment: All my app is based on double[][]. How can I put it to a func?

Comment: Using raw arrays was probably a bad idea. Your app should be based on using the `std::vector` or `std::array` types as I mentioned. May be you can manage to do something with `double[][]` without specifying the row size at the parameter declaration. I won't recommend to do that though.#

Comment: Can I use threads for such for loops? for (int x = 0; x < (N / 2); x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < (N / 2); y++) {
                    A[x][y] = a[x][y];
                }
            }

Comment: @Prazhak What have _threads_ to do with your question actually? You can use `std::thread` in for loops, yes.

Comment: I must use threads, but I dont know how. I read it must be through function.

Comment: @Prazhak That's completely beyond of your original question about the error message, and using raw arrays as function parameters has absolutely nothing to do with using threads or not.